# How do I access outer functions variables inside a closure(python 2.6)?

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-nonlocal

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29#Python)

I need to access outer functions variables in a similar manner as using the 'nonlocal' keyword from python 3.x. Is there some way to do that in python 2.6? (Not necessarily using the nonlocal keyword)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always use helper objects in that case:

```
def outerFunction():
    class Helper:
        val = None
    helper = Helper()

    def innerFunction():
        helper.val = "some value"
```

This also comes in handy when you start a new thread that should write a value to the outer function scope. In that case, `helper` would be passed as an argument to `innerFunction` (the thread's function).

Comment: the Helper class doesn't provide any __init__, so when I construct the Helper instance (helper = Helper()), what will happen? Does Helper() just return a instance with one class attribute?

Comment: @Alcott: Yes, the class attribute defaults to `None` and then you change it to an instance attribute by `helper.val = ...`. That's the simplest definition possible for solving this problem, I think.